# How to create a matrix from a generating set

Tags: python, matrix, sage

I am trying to form a matrix using a generating set of some vectors `(v1, v2, v3)`, where each element represents binary data.

I want the code to use the vectors in the set and create a matrix with the zero vector, each of the row vectors, and the combinations `v1+v2`, `v1+v3`, `v2+v3` and `v1+v2+v3`, ie. all the possible linear combinations with `0` and `1` as coefficients.

I've tried using for loops, but I end up with repeats. I've also been able to do it by doing each of the operations but this isn't feasible for generating sets with many vectors.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]])
```

I want to create a new matrix made from all possible linear combinations of the row vectors from the above matrix A.

The output should contain the following:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 
[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0], 
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], 
[1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0], 
[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
```

Comment: You'll get a better response if you include a small [mcve] with a concrete example of   your inputs and the desired output. [ask]

Comment: I don't really have anything other than just operations of different rows from this matrix, so I'm not sure what to put as my minimal reproducible example. I was wondering if there was a better way to add all the row vectors from a matrix without typing it out by hand. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Only 1 and 0 as the coefficient? So only sums? Like you don't want v1-v2 as an output?

Comment: Yes, the reason I only want the sums is because I am doing this in binary.

Comment: What's the expected output for the matrix you've given?

Comment: We want a matrix made up of the following vectors: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1], [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

v = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]]) # v1, v2, v3

l = [] # creating a list of possible combinations [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
for j in range(2, v.shape[0]+1):
    comb = combinations(np.arange(v.shape[0]), j)  
    for i in list(comb): 
        l.append(i)

final = np.zeros((len(l), v.shape[1]))  # creating final matrix 

for i in range(len(l)): # filling final matrix based on combinations
    for j in (l[i]):
        final[i] += v[j]

final = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,v.shape[1])), v, final%2), axis=0)

#array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
#       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#       [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
#       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
#       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at this problem is that you have a set of coefficients:

```
coeffs = [0, 1]
```

The goal is to get all combinations of the coefficients multiplied by the vectors. Mathematically, you want to apply the following coefficients to your vectors:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations_with_replacement, permuations
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]])

N = len(A)
all_coeffs = (
    chain.from_iterable(
        list(set(permutations(x, N))) for x in combinations_with_replacement(coeffs, N)
    )
)
print(list(all_coeffs))
#[(0, 0, 0),
# (1, 0, 0),
# (0, 1, 0),
# (0, 0, 1),
# (0, 1, 1),
# (1, 1, 0),
# (1, 0, 1),
# (1, 1, 1)]
```

So you need to take the dot product of each of the coefficients with each of the rows in `A`, and then "sum" the result. Since you're working with binary numbers, the addition operation can be achieved using the `xor` operator. Finally you can concatenate the results together.

Putting this all together:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

N = len(A)
mat = np.concatenate(
    [
        reduce(xor, (a*b for a, b in zip(c, A)))
        for c in (
            chain.from_iterable(
                list(set(permutations(x, N))) for x in 
                combinations_with_replacement(coeffs, N)
            )
        )
    ]
)
print(mat)
#[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
# [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
# [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
# [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
# [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
# [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0]
# [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
# [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```